# How do I call a table that is inside a table in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, types

I am working with an Age Of Empire II API (https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/technologies) and there are tables that call other tables.

The problem is that I don't know how to show that data.
I will leave information on how I have shown the data in the first table (this is done with Mat table).

The address of this API is: https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/structure/archery_range

But anyway add an image with the content.

**technologies.model.ts**

```
export class Technologies {
    id: number; 
    name: string; 
    description: string; 
    expansion: string;
    age: string;
    develops_in: string;
    cost: string;
    build_time: number;
    applies_to: [];
}
```

**technologies.component.ts**

```
export class TechnologiesComponent implements OnInit {

  technologies: Technologies[] = [];
  tech: Technologies;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'expansion', 'age', 'cost', 'build_time'];
  dataSource : any;

  constructor(private gameService: GameService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gameService.getTechnologies().subscribe(
      res => {
        let x;
        x=res['technologies'];

        x.forEach(element => {
          this.tech = new Technologies();
          this.tech.id = element['id'];
          this.tech.name = element['name'];
          this.tech.description = element['description'];
          this.tech.expansion = element['expansion'];
          this.tech.age = element['age'];
          this.tech.build_time = element['build_time'];
          this.technologies.push(this.tech);              
        });
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
        this.dataSource.data = this.technologies;
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }
}
```

**technologies.component.html**

```
<div class="container mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table-container">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> id</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Descripción </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="expansion">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Expansión </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.expansion}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Era </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="cost">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Costo </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cost}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="build_time">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tiempo de Construcción</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.build_time}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image: Array technologies API]

Comment: What do you mean by "calling"? making an HTTP call? And by "table" are you referring to the "applies_to" key? That key is an array of URLs. You could make an HTTP call directly to get the data the same way you are getting the technologies.

Comment: @ulmas 
I understand, for a basic array it is simple, but for an array within an array. How do I show it in the html? I can't put a table inside another table

Comment: take a look to expandable rows at https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: @alessandro 
Thank you, but I made the table. I need help with the code (get ()) to show the information of that specific url

Answer (score 0):

in a mat-table when you declare in a colum

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
```

You has in the element the object in position index, you get the propertie as `element.propertie`. If the propertie is an array you can iterate over `element.propertie_array`, e.g.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Special">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Special</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let el of element.special">{{el}}</li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</ng-container>

//or 
<ng-container matColumnDef="Special">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Special</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <tr *ngFor="let el of element.special">
            <td>{{el}}</td>
        </tr>
</ng-container>
```